# java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.nutch.plugin.PluginRuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException when parsing with nutch

Tags: java, nutch

I'm beginner in Nutch. Tried out some tutorial to crawl the web from [NutchWiki](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial#Install_Nutch). Then I try to make a custom plugin for parsing with the help of [this](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/WritingPluginExample).
All configurations are made and after building using `ant` my plugin folders are there in `build/plugins` and `runtime/local/plugin` and in `apache-nutch-1.13-SNAPSHOT.job` file. When I parsed the fetched content, I got the following error.

```
Error parsing: http://example.com/: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.nutch.plugin.PluginRuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.nutch.parsefilter.TagExtractorParseFilter
    at org.apache.nutch.plugin.PluginRepository.getOrderedPlugins(PluginRepository.java:469)
    at org.apache.nutch.parse.HtmlParseFilters.<init>(HtmlParseFilters.java:35)
    at org.apache.nutch.parse.html.HtmlParser.setConf(HtmlParser.java:340)
    at org.apache.nutch.plugin.Extension.getExtensionInstance(Extension.java:163)
    at org.apache.nutch.parse.ParserFactory.getParsers(ParserFactory.java:136)
    at org.apache.nutch.parse.ParseUtil.parse(ParseUtil.java:78)
    at org.apache.nutch.parse.ParseSegment.map(ParseSegment.java:107)
    at org.apache.nutch.parse.ParseSegment.map(ParseSegment.java:45)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:243)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.nutch.plugin.PluginRuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.nutch.parsefilter.TagExtractorParseFilter
    at org.apache.nutch.plugin.Extension.getExtensionInstance(Extension.java:167)
    at org.apache.nutch.plugin.PluginRepository.getOrderedPlugins(PluginRepository.java:441)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.nutch.parsefilter.TagExtractorParseFilter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.nutch.plugin.PluginRepository.getCachedClass(PluginRepository.java:331)
    at org.apache.nutch.plugin.Extension.getExtensionInstance(Extension.java:156)
    ... 17 more
```

I can't figure what exactly is the problem and I have done all things specified in the tutorial. 
Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT : I temporarily solved this issue by hardcoding the classpath of plugin in nutch script file like:

```
CLASSPATH="${CLASSPATH}:$NUTCH_HOME/plugins/TagExtractorParseFilter/TagExtractorParseFilter.jar"
# distributed mode
EXEC_CALL=(hadoop jar "$NUTCH_JOB")

if $local; then
 EXEC_CALL=("$JAVA" $JAVA_HEAP_MAX "${NUTCH_OPTS[@]}" -classpath "$CLASSPATH")
else
.....................
```

Comment: Have you added your plugin in nutch-site.xml in the "plugin.includes" field ?

Comment: Yes. I added that. Currently I just avoided the error by hard coding the class path of  the file. But, the issue is not actually solved.

Comment: which version of Nutch you are using ?

Comment: Apache Nutch 1.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved this issue. It was due to a small mistake in my plugin.xml.

Earlier the runtime property in plugin.xml was like

```
<runtime>
      <library name="TagExtractorParseFilter">
         <export name="*"/>
      </library>
   </runtime>
```

I changed it to

```
<runtime>
      <library name="TagExtractorParseFilter.jar">
         <export name="*"/>
      </library>
   </runtime>
```

Then, it worked.